# Windows console doesn't seem to like Unicode

Tags: windows, haskell, unicode, console

I usually develop Haskell programs on Linux, and then build and test some of
them on Windows. Say, I have some console program that outputs Unicode
symbols. In particular, it happens to output copyright symbol ‘©’, like
this:

```
Copyright © 2015 Boo
```

It works fine on Arch Linux, but on Windows 7 it prints something like:

```
Copyright program_name.EXE: <stdout>: commitAndReleaseBuffer: invalid
argument (invalid character)
```

I'm not sure, but I think it's should be feasible to output unicode symbols
in Windows console without any additional magic.

Here are two questions:

1. Is it Windows' or Haskell's fault?
2. How can I fix it?

P.S. [MinGHC](https://github.com/fpco/minghc) has been used, since it has
GHC 7.10.

Comment: You need to call [`WriteConsoleW`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687401) (note the "W" suffix on wide-character APIs), however that's done in Haskell.

Comment: @eryksun, I naively thought that high-level Haskell libraries can handle this for me...

Comment: Try running `chcp 65001` before running your program.

Comment: @chi, Great, thank you. This sort of question is probably a duplicate, however, in case it's not, please add your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @chi, codepage 65001 (UTF-8) is buggy in the console server (conhost.exe) due to how it assumes byte strings are ANSI (e.g. one byte per character in Western locales). This causes it to incorrectly report the number of bytes written to `WriteFile`, which leads to buggy output. What's worse is encoding input to multibyte UTF-8 fails in `conhost!SrvReadConsole` because the buffer is too small, but it returns to `ReadFile` / `ReadConsoleA` that it has successfully read 0 bytes, which will be interpreted as `EOF` and typically cause interactive REPLs to exit. This is just too buggy.

Comment: Also note this long standing GHC bug on windows https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/4471

Comment: Bottom line: just don't.  If you really need Unicode, you should be writing a GUI program.

Comment: Maybe a console replacement such as conemu?  https://conemu.github.io/en/UnicodeSupport.html  Also, what does PowerShell offer?

Comment: @HarryJohnston, This is a really strange point of view. Console interface is very useful for certain kind of applications that doesn't need GUI. However, why should they be limited to ASCII? This is pathetic. Text interface is a great thing, and unicode is just the same text. We should be able to write neat console programs and bugs in windows cannot change that.

Comment: @Mark: you're free to bang your head against a brick wall if you feel you must!  My advice is that the effort required to work around the bugs isn't worth it.  (Although I have heard rumours that the console has received some attention in Windows 10; perhaps Microsoft no longer consider it a dead technology, though I wouldn't bet on it.)  Also, ja's suggestion of trying PowerShell sounds sensible; I believe it has full Unicode support.

Comment: @ja. ConEmu seems to work correctly with the unicode 65001 code page, unlike the regular console. Using ConEmu, I can not even reproduce the GHC bug 4471, at least not in a short test. Nice suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This function takes the current text encoding of a handle and makes it substitute safe characters like "?" when outputting characters that are not supported by the console (nb: it's the Windows console itself that doesn't support these characters, but most other languages with unicode support apply work-arounds by default)

```
makeSafe h = do
  e <- hGetEncoding h
  case e of
    Nothing -> return ()
    Just e1 -> do
      e' <- mkTextEncoding (show e1 ++ "//TRANSLIT")
      hSetEncoding h e'
```

It can be used at the beginning of the `main` function like this:

```
main = do
  mapM_ makeSafe [stdout,stderr,stdin]
  ...
```